# UITableView - can't select cells, cells overlap

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, didselectrowatindexpath

Really trivial table view:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 2;
}

- (float)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    return 44;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"SettingsCell"];
    UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];

    switch (indexPath.row) {
        case 0:
        {
            label.text = @"One";
            break;
        }
        case 1:
        {
            label.text = @"Two";
            break;
        }
        default:
            break;
    }

    return cell;
}
```

didSelectRowAtIndexPath does not get called when I tap on a cell.

Also the cells overlap:

[image]

What could be going on here? I can scroll the table, but I can't select the cells. At one point this was working and I can't figure out what went haywire.

I'm using a Prototype cell, and Selection is set to "Single Selection" in the storyboard. All views have userInteractionEnabled = YES.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    return 44;
}
```

Changed the return type from "float" to "CGFloat". Xcode 6.1 doesn't even flag this as a warning.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be referring to the first cell repeatedly here:

`UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];`

which could account for the text being overwritten.

Try something like:

```
if(indexPath.row == 1)
{
    cell.textLabel.text = @"One";
}
```